# How to check which JRuby version is compatible with which Java version?

Tags: version, jruby

In the JRuby release notes, I often find a particular version of JRuby is compatible with which version of Ruby. How about which version of Java runtime it is compatible with?

For example, http://jruby.org/2016/05/27/jruby-9-1-2-0 page mentions it is compatible with Ruby 2.x but says nothing about Java runtime version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its not in the release notes as its not changing between point releases (unless specified), should be around download but isn't. currently, you can find out in the project [README](https://github.com/jruby/jruby#getting-jruby)

each major version of JRuby supports the JVM supported around the time its released, later point releases usually fix support for newer Java versions but do not drop support for older ones ... thus :

JRuby 1.7.x supports Java 6 or later (7, 8, might support 9)

JRuby 9.0/1 supports Java 7 or later (8, will support Java 9)

JRuby 9.2/3 only support Java 8 or later

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jruby-1.7.27 is 'working' for me under openjdk 15 with one change:

The platform class (core/src/main/java/org/jruby/ext/ffi/Platform.java) is detecting the version based on a 1.x version string, i.e. java 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, etc. for java 5, 6, 7.

openjdk uses : 15.0.2 (as an example for java 15) for the version string.

```
    protected Platform(OS_TYPE os) {
    ... (to line 231)
    int version = 5;
    try {
        String versionString = System.getProperty("java.version");
        if (versionString != null) {
            String[] v = versionString.split("\\.");
            
            //we are looking for the major version here
            //Oracle uses: 1.8.0_101 which has the major version in the second position
            //openjdk uses: 15.0.2
            version = Integer.valueOf(v[0]);
            if(version == 1) {
                version = Integer.valueOf(v[1]);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        version = 0;
    }
    javaVersionMajor = version;
}
```

[image]

Comment: JRuby 1.7 was never tested with anything > Java 8, while it might work if it doesn't you're very likely on your own ... it's usually worth investing time into upgrading rather than hacking with a custom JRuby build.